# How to say "it is actually something that does something"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, sentence-structure

I'm just wondering how to say "it is actually (insert noun) that really (insert verb).

The context is this: 有些人说，梦想点亮未来。我不同意。

Then I want to say: 其实我觉得是注意点亮未来。

Is my use of 是 correct?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: The usage of 是 is correct. But, it is a little strange to use 注意.  Maybe you can consider 努力 or 用心.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm actually trying to talk about Jack Ma's idea to start the Alibaba company. Perhaps 思想 would work better??

Comment: How about 创新, 新思维 or 好点子?

Comment: Perfect! Would you mind just clarifying for me the meaning of 新思维 in your own words?? Thanks heaps

Comment: 新思维 means new idea, new thought, or new thinking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage of 是 is correct.

> 是 ( shì ㄕˋ )
>   〈动〉
>   (5) [表示肯定判断之词 [be]](http://www.zdic.net/z/1b/xs/662F.htm)

I think it is actually the idea that can really light up the future.
其实我觉得是主意点亮未来。
我觉得其实是主意点亮未来。
我觉得其实是主意才能真正点亮未来。

To emphasize it, you can add 应该. (contrast to 梦想)
其实我觉得应该是主意点亮未来。
我觉得其实应该是主意点亮未来。
我觉得其实应该是主意才能真正点亮未来。

You can also use 想法 or 点子 for 主意.